# Post to fb wall in my application

Tags: iphone, ios4, facebook

I made an iPhone app that represents my job offer site. I want the user to post him offers in his fb wall. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for, but a good site with various tutorials including one on FB posting http://www.raywenderlich.com/77/how-to-post-on-facebook-with-your-iphone-app